# QNetworkReply - connection established, first byte written, etc

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'd like to log the lifetime of a QNetworkReply object. This includes:

1. When the underlying socket connection is established
2. When the first byte of the request is sent
3. When the first byte of the response received
4. When the last byte of the response finished

(3) and (4) can be determined by listening for the downloadProgress signal, but I'm not sure how to do (1) and (2). Is there a way to listen on the underlying socket of a QNetworkReply? The uploadprogress signal doesn't seem to be triggered for GET requests.

Comment: Could you tell us why you need to know the first two things from your list?

Comment: I'm trying to model how long it takes to download a website.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if (1) is possible but the others are easy. Have you seen my [network trace](http://ariya.blogspot.com/2010/05/qnetworkaccessmanager-tracenet-speed.html) example? Does it not work for your case?

Comment: +1 Nice code. However I don't see how it gives answer to the second question - *When the first byte of the request is sent?*

Comment: I believe that's fairly low level. It depends on how many HTTP connections are still available, caching, pipelining, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Qt does not expose mechanism used by `QNetworkAccessManager` to get data so I think you can't accomplish neither the first nor the second task from your list.
Please remember that `QNetworkAccessManager` handles not only `http(s):` schemes but also local ones like `file:` and `qrc:` which do not require any socket connection.