# QtWebkit: how to track/modify HTTP requests?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtwebkit

I need to track/modify [QtWebkit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit.html) HTTP requests.

I have a hybrid web/desktop application prototype that uses HTML forms. Form submission is done purely in AJAX and there is no form action or classic form submit button. Everything is done using JavaScript handlers and AJAX. The problem is that I need to track the HTTP request that contains form and other data from C++ side.

I've checked that [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) has "[finished(QNetworkReply*)](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished)" signal that allows to interact with HTTP response, but it's not clear to track/modify HTTP requests in QtWebkit.

Any usable example is welcome.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I think [QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest) is a way to go, checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Ariya Hidayat's answer to [QNetworkReply - connection established, first byte written, etc..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799736/) question.
As to modifying requests take a look at [How to tell QWebPage not to load specific type of resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575245/)